Filtration on field of fractions of graded ring
Let $R = \bigoplus_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} R_i$ be a commutative graded ring, that is, $R_i \cdot R_j \subseteq R_{i+j}$ for every $i,j \in \mathbb{Z}$. Assume that $R$ is a domain, so that it has a field of fractions $Q$.
We can define a degree function $d\colon R \to \mathbb{Z} \cup \{-\infty\}$ by setting $d(0) = - \infty$ and $d(x) = i$ if $x$ is non-zero and has its maximal non-zero homogeneous component in degree $i$. From the properties of the grading one immediately checks that $d(x+y) \leq \max\{d(x),d(y)\}$ and $d(xy) = d(x) + d(y)$. This degree function induces a $\mathbb{Z}$-filtration $F_iR = \{x \in R\colon d(x) \leq i\}$ and one recovers the graded structure on $R$ by taking $\operatorname{gr}(F_\bullet R)$.
I claim we can naturally extend $d$ to $Q$ as follows: set $d(a/b) = d(a) - d(b)$. Since $a/b = x/y$ if and only if $ay = bx$, this definition of $d$ is independent of the choice of fraction representing a given element of $Q$. In $Q$, we still have the same properties of $d$ as above:

$d(x+y) \leq \max\{d(x),d(y)\}$, as $$d\left(\frac{a}{b} + \frac{x}{y}\right) = d\left(\frac{ay + bx}{by}\right) = d(ay + bx) - d(b) - d(y) \leq \max\{d(a) - d(b)\,,d(x)-d(y)\}\,.$$
$d(xy) = d(x) + d(y)$ since $$d\left(\frac{a}{b}\cdot \frac{x}{y}\right) = d(ax) - d(by) = d(a) - d(b) + d(x) - d(y)\,.$$

Hence, we also get a filtration on $Q$ by setting $$F_iQ = \{q \in Q\colon d(q) \leq i\}\,.$$ My question is, what is the graded ring $\operatorname{gr}(F_\bullet Q)$? Even in concrete examples, for instance, taking $R = k[X]$ for some field $k$, where the description of $d$ in the quotient field of rational functions $Q = k(X)$ is quite immediate, I can't seem to find any insight into the structure of $\operatorname{gr}(F_\bullet Q)$.

For the function field case, it does seem that $\operatorname{gr}(F_\bullet Q)$ is isomorphic to the Laurent polynomial ring $k[X^{\pm 1}]$. Indeed, if $\overline{p}(X)$ denotes the highest degree part of a polynomial $p(X)$, then it is immediate to verify that $p(X)/q(X)$ and $\overline{p}(X)/q(X)$ have the same image in $\operatorname{gr}(F_\bullet Q)$, and so does $\overline{p}(X)/\overline{q}(X)$. Could it be that $\operatorname{gr}(F_\bullet Q)$ is the localization of $R$ with respect to the homogeneous parts of the non-zero elements of R?
